# What is the the role of using OneVsRestClassifier wrapper around XGBClassifier?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, xgboost, multiclass-classification

I have a multiclass classficiation problem with 3 classes.

- 0 - on a given day (24h) my laptop battery did not die
- 1 - on a given day my laptop battery died before 12AM
- 2 - on a given day my laptop battery died at or after 12AM

(Note that these categories are mutually exclusive. The battery is not recharged once it died)

I am interested to know the predicted probability for each 3 classes. More specifically, I intend to derive 2 types of warning:

- If the prediction for class 1 is higher then a threshold x: 'Your battery is at risk of dying in the morning.'
- If the prediction for class 2 is higher then a threshold y: 'Your battery is at risk of dying in the afternoon.'

I can generate the the probabilities by using xgboost.XGBClassifier with the appropriate parameters for a multiclass problem.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier, OneVsOneClassifier
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

X = np.array([
[10, 10],
[8, 10],
[-5, 5.5],
[-5.4, 5.5],
[-20, -20],
[-15, -20]
])
y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2])

clf1 = XGBClassifier(objective = 'multi:softprob', num_class = 3, seed = 42) 
clf1.fit(X, y)
clf1.predict_proba([[-19, -20]])
```

Results:

```
array([[0.15134096, 0.3304505 , 0.51820856]], dtype=float32)
```

But I can also wrap this with sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier. Which then produces slightly different results:

```
clf2 = OneVsRestClassifier(XGBClassifier(objective = 'multi:softprob', num_class = 3, seed = 42))
clf2.fit(X, y)
clf2.predict_proba([[-19, -20]])
```

Results:

```
array([[0.10356173, 0.34510303, 0.5513352 ]], dtype=float32)
```

I was expecting the two approaches to produce the same results. My understanding was that XGBClassifier is also based on a one-vs-rest approach in a multiclass case, since there are 3 probabilities in the output and they sum up to 1.

Can you tell me where the difference comes from, and how the respective results should be interpreted? And most important, which is approach is better suited to solve my problem.

Comment: `clf2` should have `num_class=2`, because the `OneVsRestClassifier` distills the classes before they reach the `XGBClassifier`.  Also, try setting `objective='binary:logistic'` in `clf2`.

Comment: Thanks, @BenReiniger. With the modifications you suggested, the 2 classifiers do give the same results. Also thanks for shedding light on how OneVsRestClassifier() works. Makes actually sense that it should take a binary classifier.